# JSON webhook happens only on initial save, not edits?

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm troubleshooting a problem getting Cognito Forms to webhook into an application of mine, and I want to be sure that I'm testing properly.  After running it through RequestBin, it looks as though Cognito will send the webhook after an initial submission, but will not re-send the webhook if the submission is edited and saved.

Is that right?

Is there any way to modify that behaviour?

Is there a way to create a new "entry" without having to retype everything in an existing one?

Answer (score 1):

Cognito Forms currently support "chaining" forms via the public link.  That is, in form 1, you can create a redirect url with parameters consisting of entry data from that form to pre-fill data on form 2.  As an example, if you make your redirect url (in Submission Settings): `https://cognitoforms.com/myorg/mysecondform?entry={Name:{First:[Name.First],Last:[Name.Last]}}`
 where the elements in square brackets are inserted field values and `myorg` and `mysecondform` are your organization and form names, then the second form will come up with data prefilled from the first form.

On our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/b/ZS1698De/idea-board), we have a [card](https://trello.com/c/QVKTKkSk/127-conditional-integrations) for more advanced web hook support in Cognito Forms.  Stop by and up-vote it to help us get this feature prioritized!

Disclaimer: I am an engineer on the Cognito Forms team